# Python module not found after installing anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Hope everyone is doing fine :)

I'm new to python, so I'm having trouble cause I've installed anaconda (for machine learning) and now, my local projects in VS Code with python, don't find modules installed from `pip install`.

I've searched online and I guess it has something to do with the path... Here's the path when I install the module:

```
user_stuff.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

I want to install modules into my project on desktop, here's the path:

```
user_stuff.../Desktop/python-project
```

I keep getting this error when trying to import:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode'
```

How do I change this? It's really frustrating :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess your pip is referring to the pip provided by the system, it should be now referring to the pip provided by anaconda.

$ which pip

$ alias pip="/Users/my-username/anaconda3/bin/pip"

$ pip install qrcode

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I uninstalled anaconda and used only python with jupyter. But I will try this approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use jupyter notebook in vs code? I prefer it because there you can easily select the environment you are using. And if you want to pip install anything in a environment you have to first activate it in the console with conda activate *env name*

Comment: Hey Toms, thanks for your time :) Actually, I don't so I will certainly investigate and improve my IDE with jupyter ;)